# Maven Javadoc generator String Index out of range

Tags: java, maven, exception, javadoc

When I want to generate Javadocs with the maven-javadoc-plugin, the process fails with the error message:

```
[ERROR] javadoc: error - String index out of range: -6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
```

I tried enabling Debug Mode of Maven, Debug mode of the Javadoc Plugin, Debug mode of the javadoc generator itself. I have not gotten any more information than the message above. Not even a hint what class it fails to generate JavaDoc for.

Searching for this problem doesn't lead to much results either as all queries end in results for documentation about `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` or other exception related problems.

I use version 3.2.0 of the `maven-javadoc-plugin`. But it doesn't seem to matter what version I use as the problem is also existent in version 2.7.

What I've found out so far is, that this error only occurs if I utilize stuff from a special dependency (currently the problem gets resolved if I remove all references to that dependency in code).

Said dependency is not public and was installed using the `mvn install:install-file` command. The classes in the dependency have been compiled with **Java 6**.

This is my last hope to get some information and maybe a solution to the problem.

Edit 1: It is definitely that dependency. If I manually remove it from the 'classpath' of the javadoc command (options file) then the error disappears.

Could it have something to do with me having a package name that matches exactly the package name used in the dependency?

Comment: If it is a data error (like javadoc with more params than there actually are in the method signature), then a code checker like SonarLint might find the spot. Though it is a bug nevertheless.

Comment: @JoopEggen the dependency has no attached javadocs/source and the class that utilizes the dependency doesn't have any javadocs either. If I delete this class, the error disappears. As soon as I use anything of that dependency the error comes back.